# Find equation of tangents to curve

Tags: derivatives, curves

> Find the equations of tangents to the curve $3x^2 - y^2 = 8$ which pass through the point 
>   $(4/3,0)$

I googled it and got [this yahoo answers question](http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130320191058AAEW7PP) which has 2 contradicting answers.

I did it the first way. but got m = 1/3 and the points of tangency are ( 2 , 2 ) & ( 2 , - 2)
But my book does it the second way but reaches the equation y=0 (slope is 0)

I am absolutely confused

> Also, I found a contradiction here:$$x-x_1=m(y-y_1)
> $$
>   $$x-x_1=\frac{a}b{} (y-y_1)$$
>   $$bx-bx_1=ay-ay_1$$
>   $$y=\frac{bx-bx_1+ay_1}{a}$$
>   $$y=mx$$
>   Here slope m becomes b/a instead of a/b. What did i do wrong?

I have exam tmrw. Quick answer would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Have you graphed it, to get some insight into what sort of answer you expect?

Comment: The second method only works for points lying on the curve. $(4/3,0)$ isn't one of them.

Comment: $x-x_1=m(y-y_1)$ should be $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$

Comment: The second solution you linked to is really bad.

Comment: Thank you. Sabyasachi is correct. part 2 is solved.

Comment: First method is correct?? What is slope? point of contact? I equated dy/dx and slope of line using $y_2-y_1/x_2-x_1$ and got $x=2, y=+/-2$ and slope=$3$... plz verify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slope of the line passing through $(x,y)$ and $(4/3,0)$ is given by:
$$
m_1(x,y) = \frac{y}{x-4/3}.
$$
The tangent line passing through $(x,y)$ on your curve is perpendicular to the gradient of your function:
$$
Df(x,y) = \left(\begin{array}{c}6x \\ -2y\end{array}\right)
$$
so it is parallel to the vector
$$
  \left(\begin{array}{c}2y \\ 6x\end{array}\right)
$$
which has slope 
$$
m_2(x,y) = \frac{6x}{2y}.
$$
It must be $m_1(x,y)=m_2(x,y)$ i.e. one must find solutions of the system:
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{y}{x-4/3} = \frac{3x}{y}\\
3x^2 - y^2 = 8
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: So is my answer correct?